# [kubuntu]Two-line title for taskbar windows

Tags: kde, kubuntu

Sorry for my English.
I am using Kubuntu 20.04.
After a recent update, the taskbar windows titles were displayed in 2 lines as in the screenshot below:

[image]

This is convenient for me. But after another (more recent) update, it returned back to normal, i.e. one line with "..." if the title is too long.

How can I restore it to show 2 lines instead of just one?

Thank you

Comment: I think that happens automatically when you make your panel higher.

Comment: thank you for the comment, however I didn't touch the panel. It was really after an update.

Comment: Maybe the update changed at which height the lines get wrapped.

Comment: Yes maybe, that and the font size. Is there a way to change that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Natalie's comments (thank you!) made me think about decreasing the font size of the interface. I typed "font" in the app launcher and I changed the font size in "General" from 10 pt to 9.5 pt. And now I have exactly what I want.

*Note 1:* the font is smaller not just for the taskbar but also the main interface.

*Note 2:* here "font" and "General" might not be 100 accurate, as my interface is not in English. It's something like: System configuration → Fonts → General.

Comment: Alternatively you could make the panel higher with right click > enter edit mode.